# AC line from inverter grounded to vehicle chassis

Tags: ac, dc, inverter

What happens if a hot line from an inverter powered by a vehicle battery contacts the vehicle chassis?  This will form a circuit connecting the hot line from the inverter to the negative terminal of the vehicle battery.  Does the DC battery somehow accept the AC electricity, or does the current not flow, leaving the chassis hot?

Comment: that depends on the inverter, if the output is isolated from the input nothing happens . else some fuse probably blows.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsmWgV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Floating output. (b) Neutralised output.*

If the inverter is fully isolated then grounding either L1 or L2 does not cause affect the battery circuit. Shorting L1 and L2 to each other directly or through the chassis should trip the inverter output protection.

If the output is neutralised by connecting one of the secondaries to chassis then a ground fault on L1 should trip the protective device. Again this should not affect the battery circuit.

---

From the comments:

> Hmm so if one of the AC leads from the inverter is tied to the vehicle chassis, that means that if the other line somehow ends up tied to the chassis of an AC device (for example, by way of faulty/damaged wiring), touching the metal skin of that device would likely cause AC current to flow through the body?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsjmbA.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Correct earthing of appliances protects against live chassis.*

If your appliances are earthed properly then the situation is exactly the same as domestic or office electrical supply. The earthed case prevents the user being exposed to high voltages and will cause the protective device to trip.

If you omit the earth then you risk electric shock.

Comment: Hmm so if one of the AC leads from the inverter is tied to the vehicle chassis, that means that if the other line somehow ends up tied to the chassis of an AC device (for example, by way of faulty/damaged wiring), touching the metal skin of that device would likely cause AC current to flow through the body?  Depending on footwear, how much floor insulation is present, what else you're touching at the same time, etc

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your basically correct.You may get Ac ripple into the Dc system - but often its not an issue.

The reason this is done in Australia is to - ground the Ac neutral side to earth on an inverter - is for the Multiple-Earth-Neutral, or MEN link, which stabilizes the core-balance relay inside the Residual Current Device ( called an RCD ) to operate in the correct manner. Normally an RCD is fitted to an electrical switchboard in a building with an earth stake to ground the system. This set up is fine as there is no way you can ever touch the electrical wiring unless you deliberately open the switch board to access the contacts. But in a mobile AC set up this is not so. It is often exposed and easily accessed and because it runs off 12 volts Dc many nievely believe it's safe. In many cases with DC systems the battery Dc negative line is used as ground - as there is no other method of doing such.

Without connecting the Inverter Ac out to ground, it will disable the RCD protection device from tripping when an active ground fault occurs in a mains operated appliance.

HOWEVER - I am totally against this whole concept - and have argued with electrical guys over it for the very reason that most MOBILE installations do not use a ground stake and if the Ac line was ever reversed then active would be the metal case. 
To fix all of this Inverters should be double insulated - so there is no exposed metal case to worry about.the reason a metal case is even used is to heatsink the power devices and shield the PCB from radio frequency radiation into other equipment. Today this is easily done in double insulated devices.

I work on inverters in mobile installations that can be thousands of watts in output at 230 volts Ac and the systems have no ground stake because they are on a fibre-glass hull boat or in a recreational vehicle of an aeroplane - often with idiots using them who would not know positive from negative.